# What is the range of the inverse discrete fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the range of the real discrete inverse fourier transform? And would the range be the same for both 1D and 2D version of the transform?

To state it in a different manner if we know the {min, max, length} of $X$, do we know the range of $\mathbf{F}^{-1}(X)$?

Comment: Assume $(X_n)_{n=0}^{N-1}$ is the input vector. If the inverse DFT is defined as something like $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}X_n e^{ink/N}$, then we have $\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}X_n e^{ink/N}\right| \leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|X_n|$. So, the inverse DFT samples are bounded in magnitude by the average of the magnitudes of the input samples. This bound holds for any input vector, and it's the best we can say in general, since equality is achieved when, for example, $X_n = 1$ for $n=0$ and $X_n = 0$ for $n \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind copy-pasting it as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer?

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need any more details or if my assumption regarding the definition of the IDFT is incorrect.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the input vector by $(X_n)_{n=0}^{N-1}$. I assume that the inverse DFT is defined as something like
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}X_n e^{2\pi ink/N}$$
By the triangle inequality, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}X_n e^{2\pi ink/N}\right|
&\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |X_n e^{2\pi ink/N}| \\
&= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |X_n| \\
\end{aligned}$$
which shows that the inverse DFT samples are bounded in magnitude by the average of the magnitudes of the input samples. This bound holds for any input vector, and it's the best we can say in general, since equality is achieved when, for example,
$$X_n = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 0 \\
0 & n \neq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$